# PHP Mail where the email isn’t being received on a certain email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have my clients server – let’s call it `clientserver.com`.

Emails sent from the server using the PHP `mail` function don’t get received by an email account on that server – let’s call it `email@clientserver.com`. However, if I set the email ID to my own personal one it is received without any problem.

Is there anything you guys can see that I could possibly add to the headers or anything else to ensure that this `email@clientserver.com` address receives the contact form email?

I’ve tried PHPMailer with no luck either.

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
    die('Error: Missing variables');
}

$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

$to='email@clientserver.com';

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$subject = 'Contact form enquiry';
$body='Dear Client,'."\n\n";
$body.='The following enquiry has been sent through.'."\n\n";
$body.='Name: '.$name."\n";
$body.='Email: '.$email."\n";
$body.='Phone: '.$phone."\n";
$body.='Message: '.$message."\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-femail@clientserver.com")) {
    die('Mail sent');
} else {
    die('Error: Mail failed');
}

?>
```

Comment: I might be wrong but this sounds more like a problem with configuration/settings than it does your PHP code.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada: Config where exactly? Server-side it's working. Email account in question receives emails just not from the server in question.

Comment: Perhaps the way that the server is set up to receive emails (or in your hosting plan/website email settings?).  But again, I don't really know.  It just seems like that would be the only reason since it works fine when you submit to a personal address.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to define security settings among other things, some smtp servers accept different details. I had a problem similar to this and i also had to allow the php extension "php_opnessl".

for example: live uses a setup like this

```
$mail -> Port = 587;
$mail -> SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$mail -> Host = "smtp.live.com";
```

while gmail is:

```
$mail -> Port = 465;
$mail -> SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
$mail -> Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Let me know if any of this helps